# Counting occurrences of chars in Given string Using stream API

Tags: java, string, java-stream

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FindOccurenceOfChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "Ranjan Kumar Singh";
        Map<Object, Long> repetedChars = name.chars()
       .mapToObj(c->(char) c)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .map(u -> u.toUpperCase(u))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l, 
                 Collectors.counting()));
        
System.out.println("Repeated characters are..." + repetedChars);

    }
}
//Output I am Getting:-
```

// Repeated characters are...{ =2, A=3, R=2, S=1, U=1, G=1, H=1, I=1, J=1, K=1, M=1, N=3}

```
//Output should be exactly like --> {A=3, R=2, S=1, U=1, G=1, H=1, I=1, J=1, K=1, M=1, N=3}
```

Comment: so the question is how to filter the withe spaces?

Comment: BTW Why `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` ? converting a stream to list to convert back to stream?! || BTW2 And what is `u -> u.toUpperCase(u)`? just use `Character::toUpperCase` || I would probably have done something like `name.codePoints().filter(Character::isAlphabetic).map(Character::toUpperCase).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));`

Answer (score 1):

Apply `filter()` method while counting characters to ensure only non-whitespace characters are counted

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "Ranjan Kumar Singh";
        Map<Object, Long> repetedChars = name.chars()
                .mapToObj(c->(char) c)
                .filter(c -> !Character.isWhitespace(c))
                .map(Character::toUpperCase)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l, 
                 Collectors.counting()));
        
System.out.println("Repeated characters are..." + repetedChars);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at what @user16320675 said about the redundant streaming